# Jquery datepicker month/year menu issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery datepicker with month and year menu [like this](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year),

Here if you click on month menu, keep it open and then click on year dropdown then month menu gets close and year menu appears.

but something is wrong in my code, when I open month menu, keep it open and then click on year dropdown then year menu gets closed automatically.

So i find myself unable to think where to start debugging from, can any body plese help me ?

Comment: @MoazzamKhan there is no special code used, just simple code to initialize jquery datepicker or I admit that I don't know what code should I put, because it just another jquery datepicker code

Comment: If its working in the jQuery demo there must be something different in your code.

Comment: @MoazzamKhan, yes he somewhere handled event propagation, which is not on jquery site, at least i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a case of event propogation,which creates a simulation like multiple listeners are attached.

to solve, in click event of calendars div write this line `event.stopPropagation();`

or

let other come with proper answer